# Can't connect to sql from php with ip

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

So i have this script for connection to sql server.

```
//SET CONNECTION TO MSQL
$serverName = "";
$uid = "user";
$pwd = "password";
$databaseName = "database";

//BUILD CONNECTION ARRAY
$connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>$uid,
                         "PWD"=>$pwd,
                         "Database"=>$databaseName);

/* Connect using SQL Server Authentication. */
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);


//TEST CONNECTION
if( $conn ) {
echo "Connection established.<br />";

}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

I have this script localy on the server and remote.
My mission is to be able to connect remotely.

So if i try `$serverName = "SRV\SQLEXPRESS";` and runt this localy i gott message: Connection established.

If i change the server name for the local ip and test it locally i got this message:

> Connection could not be established.
> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1] => 2 [code] => 2 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server

I have been talking to the network administration and they say that the port is open and the firewall accepts connections both locally and remote.

If i try to connect remotely i got the message that tha odbc driver cannot be found.

So what seems to be the problem, and what should i do to find it? What can i test?

**EDIT**

As suggested in the comments i tried:

```
$serverName = "tcp:192.168.0.242, 51484";
```

And it worked. I dont know why that port is beeing used? sql configuration manager says 1433 is used?

Remote connection to public ip still tells me that odbc driver is missing?!

Comment: `Named Pipes` is a connection for on the same machine. Consider prefixing your servername with `tcp:` so you force the TCP protocol. Example: `tcp:your-hostname,1433`

Comment: Or you need to enable the TCP/IP protocol on your local SQL Server instance (it's disabled by default).

Comment: @Zhorov if i go to the Sql Server Configuration manager and check for Client Protocols. The TCP/IP is enabled. Is this what you ment?

Comment: @BjörnC, yes, SQL Server Configuration Manager, SQL Server Network Configuration and SQL Native Client Configuration (if I remember correctly)

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts so i tried: $serverName = "tcp:192.168.0.242, 1433"; And now the message says that the target computer active denied the connection?!

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts should Named pipes be enabled in sql server configuration?

Comment: Named pipes should only be enabled if you are trying to connect from the same machine. Which I assume you are not doing. If you are on windows you can check the firewall using powershell: `Test-NetConnection 192.168.0.242 -Port 1433`

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts WARNING: TCP connect to 192.168.0.242:1433 failed. what can i do about this?

Comment: Make sure no firewalls are blocking inbound or outbound. Both on the network, and on the client & server. Make sure the IP address and port you use is the correct one, Are you connected to the VPN...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @preben said in the comments, this was solved by adding "tcp" to the serverName.

```
$serverName = "tcp:192.168.0.242, 51484";
```